# How to fix multiple IF condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to generate an output from two column like,

```
 A   B  C
 1   1  TP
 1  -1  FN
-1   1  FP
-1  -1  TN
```

I used the equation below in `C1`.

```
=IF(A1=B1,IF(A1=1&B1=1,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1&B1=1,"FP","FN"))
```

and the out put is like,

```
 A   B  C
 1   1  TN
 1  -1  FN
-1   1  FN
-1  -1  TN
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with the above equation. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [&](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d?CorrelationId=1972d2d1-4006-4d86-9913-07c0c4f5ca42&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is what SCB said, that is to have two 'AND'ed conditions, you need to use the `AND()` function, because otherwise, you get the `&` concatenator that is, for example your first formula is turning into:

```
=IF(1=1,IF(1=1&1=1,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1&B1=1,"FP","FN"))
```

Which becomes...

```
=IF(TRUE,IF(1="11"=1,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1&B1=1,"FP","FN"))
```

Then...

```
=IF(TRUE,IF(FALSE=1,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1&B1=1,"FP","FN"))
```

Then...

```
=IF(TRUE,IF(FALSE,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1&B1=1,"FP","FN"))
```

---

You should change it to:

```
=IF(A1=B1,IF(AND(A1=1,B1=1)"TP","TN"),IF(AND(A1=-1,B1=1),"FP","FN"))
```

Or shorter...

```
=IF(A1=B1,IF(A1=1,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1,"FP","FN"))
```

---

Though I think a fun way to do the same thing would be:

```
=IF(A1=B1,"T","F")&IF(B1=1,"P","N")
```

Since 'like' always gives `T`, and if B1 is positive, then it's always "P", then concatenate the two results.

Comment: Providing the fun way of doing this deserves a plus.

Comment: Of course! I was kind of confused why the use of the `&` wasn't throwing an error but that makes a lot of sense, thanks. And nice thinking on the fun way.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
A1=1&B1=1
```

Try

```
AND(A1=1,B1=1)
```

Though even then, since you've already confirmed that A and B either are or aren't the same, you only need to check one of their values in the secondary IF statements.

```
=IF(A1=B1,IF(A1=1,"TP","TN"),IF(A1=-1,"FP","FN"))
```